# java.util.Scanner Object Declaration not Allowed Here

Tags: java, variables, java.util.scanner, declaration

I have to use Scanner objects in different scopes as presented below:

```
public String fidentifier (String u)
{
    try {
        Scanner t = new Scanner( new File( "ubasic.dat") );
        //Some Statements
    } catch( FileNotFoundException e ){
            System.out.println( "Exception : " + e );
    }
}

public String didentifier(String cat)
{
    try {
        if( cat.equals("Government") )
                Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("ugov.dat") );
        else
              Scanner s = new Scanner( new File("uhc.dat") );
        //Some Statements
    } catch( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            System.out.println( "Exception : " + e );
    }
}
```

As I clearly declared Scanner objects in two different methods, I am still getting error pointing out that Scanner object declaration is not allowed in method `didentifier()`.

Point me out where I'm wrong.

Comment: Make a [mcve] and [ask], you can't have that error with what you posted...

Comment: You can't have that `if` statement with the two scanner things. SImply just do... `Scanner s;`  and then inside the if statements do `s = new Scanner(...);`

Comment: @Tunaki If you are asking for statements written after the comment `//Some Statements`, then these Scanner objects are reading lines from the file and the read line is then split with a delimiter to check for individual Strings.

Comment: No. Read the page [mcve] carefully.

Comment: @3kings Thanks for the tip. That eradicated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and declare as much Scanners as you want...(it is a bad practice but there is not technical limitation for that...)

> ...*Point me out where I'm wrong*....

The error is: ***Scanner cannot be resolved to a variable***
The reason of the error is that you are trying to declare an object in a if else scope but no are using  curly braces **{   }**

replace the code in the method for this:

```
if (cat.equals("Government")) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("ugov.dat"));
} else {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("uhc.dat"));
    // Some Statements
}
```

and everything will work fine...

---

at the end you can have one global Scanner object and you just can change the reference of the object.

```
public String didentifier(String cat)
{
    try
    {
        if( cat.equals("Government") )
              s = new Scanner( new File("ugov.dat") );
        else
              s = new Scanner( new File("uhc.dat") );
        //Some Statements
    }catch( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            System.out.println( "Exception : " + e );
    }
//your Return here...
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The statement after an `if` has it's own scope.  It doesn't make sense to declare a variable which doesn't exist on the next line as it is out of scope.  The simplest thing to do is to use a variable or ?:

```
String file;
if( cat.equals("Government") )
     file = "ugov.dat";
else
     file = "uhc.dat";
Scanner s = new Scanner( new File(file) );
```

or

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( new File(cat.equals("Government") ? "ugov.dat": "uhc.dat" ) );
```